# Can we remove the Stack Store ad (or bring back the store)?

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

I'm assuming that this is a network wide ad:

[image: What?!]

as it's not in the [Community ads](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3957/community-promotion-ads-2012) meta post over at Super User.  Can we make sure this ad doesn't show up.  I got really excited thinking you brought it back, and then was devasted to find out all my hopes and dreams were ground into a pulp.

## OR

You can bring back the shop and make the world a happier place.

Answer (score 7):

We're in the process of getting to the bottom of this. The ad itself was turned off on a 'master' level, but remained on in a couple of flights.

Logic suggests that turning them off on a master level would deactivate it globally, even if turned on somewhere, but that was not the case here.

When I have more information I'll pass it along! :)

Comment: Thanks!  Interesting problem your facing :)

Comment: For the record, we prefer the store coming back to this being fixed ;)